# MySQL Query 127 seconds of execution

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-schema

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM magnitudes t1 INNER JOIN value_magnitudes t2 ON t1.id = t2.magnitude_id WHERE t1.floor_id = 42 AND t2.reading_date = (SELECT Max(reading_date) FROM value_magnitudes WHERE t2.magnitude_id = t1.id);
```

And my DB Schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE magnitudes (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255)  NULL  ,
  sdi_id VARCHAR(255)  NULL  ,
  sdi_id_floor VARCHAR(255)  NULL  ,
  visible TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED  NULL  ,
  history TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED  NULL  ,
  created_at DATETIME  NULL  ,
  updated_at DATETIME  NULL  ,
  floor_id INT(11)  NULL  ,
  unit VARCHAR(255)  NULL  ,
  kind_id INT(11)  NULL  ,
  sample_time INT(11)  NULL  ,
  history_from DATETIME  NULL DEFAULT 2011-02-22 11:18:07   ,
PRIMARY KEY(id));

CREATE TABLE value_magnitudes (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
  value FLOAT  NULL  ,
  magnitude_id INT(11)  NULL  ,
  sdi_belongs_id VARCHAR(255)  NULL  ,
  reading_date DATETIME  NULL  ,
  created_at DATETIME  NULL  ,
  updated_at DATETIME  NULL    ,
PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

What I actually want is, get the last `value_magnitudes` depending on the last `updated_at` by `magnitudes.id on values_magnitudes.magnitude_id`

Thanks.

Comment: An index on value_magnitudes.magnitude_id would help - but you should always run an EXPLAIN against a query that's you're testing for slow running, that'll show you how it's working "behind the scenes", and is a vital component of the developers database toolkit

Comment: Actually I'm a programmer and the database was already done XD, and I'm nervous everytime I have to do a SQL query in this DB and I cannot spend time to improve or something related to the DB, just some SQL, even I'm not the SQL guy neither and anyone can't help, so I think stackoverflow was the best solution, asking. By the way, thanks for helping.

Comment: If you can't spend time to add that index, or if the SQL guy can't add the correct indexes for the database design (value_magnitudes.magnitude_id  against magnitudes.id should be indexed with a foreign key constraint), then it'll be almost impossible to improve the speed of your query

Comment: Okay thanks, I will tell them, I just try to find a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 VM.* FROM value_magnitudes VM, magnitudes M  WHERE M.id = VM.id ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

Comment: I did this query to test `SELECT TOP 1 VM.* FROM value_magnitudes VM, magnitudes M WHERE M.id = VM.magnitude_id AND M.floor_id = 42 ORDER BY updated_at DESC` but still long time of execution, which could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT VM.* FROM value_magnitudes VM, magnitudes M  WHERE M.id = VM.id ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 0,1;`